# How to load an image from a URL?

Tags: meteor

My img tag is :

```
<img style="position:absolute; ....."
        src="http://localhost/RESSOURCES/albums/.../CePetitAlbum.png"/>
```

'RESOURCES' is at the same level as client, public, server
No error, but no picture, And yet the image is in the specified directory.

Anyone with an idea to solve my problem?

Comment: You forgot to add your code...

Comment: 1. Your "answer" should be an edit to your question, this is not an answer. Please take the time to read how this site works. 2. Any non-script asset is included in the app bundle, so unless you put it in `/public`, it won't be in the bundle, so it won't be on the server. If it is too large for your server, I guess that you should store them in an external location and have links to them on the server. I am assuming that you are deploying to Galaxy, and Galaxy is not meant to server as a storage server for large files.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `/public` directory.

Take a look at the [docs](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories)

> All files inside a top-level directory called `public/` are served as-is to the client. When referencing these assets, do not include `public/` in the URL, write the URL as if they were all in the top level. For example, reference `public/bg.png` as `<img src='/bg.png' />`. This is the best place for `favicon.ico`, `robots.txt`, and similar files.
>
> **source:** [Meteor Docs](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories)