# Meteor - load an image by its url

Tags: image, meteor

(Excuse me, my previous question was wrong)

Everything is in the subject. My img tag is :

'RESOURCES' is at the same level as client, public, server
No error, but no picture !!! And yet the image is in the specified directory.

Anyone with an idea to solve my problem?
Thank you
YC

Comment: Please edit your question to be more clear. Specify the problem, add relevant code if any and show your efforts in solving it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load an image from a URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41544054/how-to-load-an-image-from-a-url)

Answer (score 0):

You may try placing you images under: `/public/images`
Eg. `/public/images/this.jpg`

And access it like so:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="/images/this.jpg">
```